# Jest giving TS2582 ERROR while execution. event after having module packages

Tags: unit-testing, next.js, jestjs

I am using nextjs 13, with apollo, and I want to create unit test for APIs I created with apollo server in nextjs 13.
but I am getting.

```
 FAIL  __test__/pages/unit/server.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    __test__/pages/unit/server.spec.ts:4:1 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha`.

    4 describe("GraphQL API Tests", () => {
      ~~~~~~~~
    __test__/pages/unit/server.spec.ts:5:3 - error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha`.

    5   it("returns data as expected for GET_WITHDRAW_LINK query", async () => {
        ~~
    __test__/pages/unit/server.spec.ts:67:5 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

    67     expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
           ~~~~~~
```

I am getting this error even after I have installed the required dependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/test-sequencer": "^29.5.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.4",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "4.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/client-preset": "4.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/expect": "^24.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  }
```

my jest.config

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: "../",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/config/jest.setup.js"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
  },
};
```

jest.setup

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

package.Json script

```
    "test": "jest --config ./config/jest.config.js ./__test__ "
```

I also tried to reinstall the modules but that didn't work also.